# SQL query to see if condition is met and nothing else

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to find out is if column anaID has the value of 22 or 23, and **no other value is assigned** for anaID for that subID/sampleID combination.

something like

```
select * from anaData where subID='2020-04-21-17' and sampleID='crazy2' 
and 
(anaID=22 or anaID=23)
and 
andID <> ??anything else??
```

I can query out all the matches and loop through them and have program logic that decides, but I'm hoping this can be done in a query.

Comment: post your desired ouput

Comment: it should return either a dataset with anaID being 22 or 23, or an empty result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select *
from anaData a
where subID = '2020-04-21-17' and
      sampleID = 'crazy2' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from anaData a2
                  where a2.subID = a.subID and a2.sampleID = a.sampleID and
                        a2.anaID not in (22, 23)
                 );
```

It turns out that you don't need `anaID in (22, 23)` in the outer query.  The `exists` takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

This works if at least one anaID 22 *or* 23 exist:

```
select subID, sampleID
from anaData 
where subID='2020-04-21-17'
  and sampleID='crazy2' 
group by subID, sampleID
having
   sum(case when anaID in (22, 23) then 1 else -100 end) > 1
```

If you want both 22 *and* 23 switch to `= 2` (assuming that the combination *subID/sampleID/anaID* is unique.

This can also be used without WHERE-conditions.